# Splitting rows from a dataset with R doesn't work on PowerBI

Tags: r, data.table, strsplit

I have a dataset with this format:

[image: Origin]

```
#albaran|fecha|cliente|estado|descrip|destinatario|direccion|cp|poblacion|observaciones
#11111|43229|C1|E1|D1|DD1|DIR1|CP1|P1|COLECCIÓN CLÁSICOS DISNEY - Entrega Nº: 11, 12, 13, 14; Grandes Enigmas - Entrega Nº: 5, 6
#22222|43229|C2|E2|D2|DD2|DIR2|CP2|P2|COLECCIÓN CLÁSICOS DISNEY - Entrega Nº: 8, 9; Otro Pedido - Entrega Nº: 1, 2
```

And I need to convert on:

[image: Format]

```
#albaran|fecha|cliente|estado|descrip|destinatario|direccion|cp|poblacion|pedido|entregas
#11111|43229|C1|E1|D1|DD1|DIR1|CP1|P1|COLECCIÓN CLÁSICOS DISNEY|11, 12, 13, 14
#11111|43229|C1|E1|D1|DD1|DIR1|CP1|P1|Grandes Enigmas|5, 6
#22222|43229|C2|E2|D2|DD2|DIR2|CP2|P2|COLECCIÓN CLÁSICOS DISNEY|8, 9
#22222|43229|C2|E2|D2|DD2|DIR2|CP2|P2|Otro Pedido|1, 2
```

I'm trying with

```
library(data.table)

hec1 <- as.data.table(dataset)
res <- hec1[,strsplit(observaciones, split = ";"),by = c("albaran", "fecha", "cliente", "estado", "descrip", "destinatario", "direccion", "cp", "poblacion")]
res[, pedido:= substring(observaciones, 1, regexpr(":", observaciones)-2)][, entregas := substring(observaciones, regexpr(":", observaciones)+2, nchar(observaciones))]
res$V1 <- NULL
res <- res[,strsplit(entregas, split = ","),by = c("albaran", "fecha", "cliente", "estado", "descrip", "destinatario", "direccion", "cp", "poblacion", "tipo_pedido")]
setnames(res, "pedido", "entregas")
res
```

But it doesn't work, show me this error:

> Error in strsplit(observaciones, split = ";") :    argumento de tipo
>   no-carácter Calls: [ -> [.data.table -> strsplit Ejecución
>   interrumpida

I think... can be the problem be the origin format? It's a `data.table`.

Thank's @prem, your example work's well on RStudio, im trying to execute this script on PowerBI Script, but show me this error

> Error in UseMethod("separate_rows_") : 
>    no applicable method for 'separate_rows_' applied to an object ...
>      ErrorCode=-2147467259
>      ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Radio.RScriptRuntimeException

When I try to use dplyr library, I recibe the following error

> DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: R script error.
>
> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
>
> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
>
> filter, lag
>
> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
>
> intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
>
> Error in UseMethod("separate_rows_") : 
>    no applicable method for 'separate_rows_' applied to an object of class >"function"
>   Calls: %>% ... separate_rows -> separate_rows.default -> separate_rows_
>   Ejecución interrumpida

This package is compatible with PowerBI https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/power-bi/service-r-packages-support

This is the code, i can't use tidyverse because it's not compatible.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)


df %>%
  separate_rows("observaciones", sep = ";") %>%
  separate(observaciones, c("pedido", "entregas"), " - Entrega Nº ")
```

Problem Solved, thanks @Prem

This is the final version:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- as.data.table(dataset)
df <- df %>%
  separate_rows("observaciones", sep = ";") %>%
  separate(observaciones, c("pedido", "entregas"), " - Entrega Nº:")
df <- df %>%
  separate_rows("entregas", sep = ", ") %>%
  separate(entregas, c("entregas"), ",")
df <- df %>%
  separate_rows("entregas", sep = "y") %>%
  separate(entregas, c("entregas"), ",")
```

Comment: Please don't post images of data, they're not very useful.

Comment: [See here on how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610).

Comment: this is perfect for `tidyr::separate_rows()`'s function

Comment: See `?tstrsplit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tidyverse` approach could be

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate_rows("observaciones", sep = ";") %>%
  separate(observaciones, c("pedido", "entregas"), " - Entrega Nº ")
```

**Output is:**

```
  albaran fecha cliente estado descrip destinatario direccion  cp poblacion                    pedido
1   11111 43229      C1     E1      D1          DD1      DIR1 CP1        P1 COLECCIÓN CLÁSICOS DISNEY
2   11111 43229      C1     E1      D1          DD1      DIR1 CP1        P1           Grandes Enigmas
3   22222 43229      C2     E2      D2          DD2      DIR2 CP2        P2 COLECCIÓN CLÁSICOS DISNEY
4   22222 43229      C2     E2      D2          DD2      DIR2 CP2        P2               Otro Pedido
        entregas
1 11, 12, 13, 14
2           5, 6
3           8, 9
4           1, 2
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(albaran = c(11111L, 22222L), fecha = c(43229L, 
43229L), cliente = c("C1", "C2"), estado = c("E1", "E2"), descrip = c("D1", 
"D2"), destinatario = c("DD1", "DD2"), direccion = c("DIR1", 
"DIR2"), cp = c("CP1", "CP2"), poblacion = c("P1", "P2"), observaciones = c("COLECCIÓN CLÁSICOS DISNEY - Entrega Nº 11, 12, 13, 14; Grandes Enigmas - Entrega Nº 5, 6", 
"COLECCIÓN CLÁSICOS DISNEY - Entrega Nº 8, 9; Otro Pedido - Entrega Nº 1, 2"
)), .Names = c("albaran", "fecha", "cliente", "estado", "descrip", 
"destinatario", "direccion", "cp", "poblacion", "observaciones"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: @Ismael Regarding the error you have mentioned as a followup question - is the package `tidyverse` or (`dplyr` & `tidyr`) installed?

Comment: You already have added `dplyr` & `tidyr` so you are good on that front. Now your data should be in `df` dataframe which doesn't seems to be the case so pass your data to `df`.

Comment: Glad that it helped!